# visual studio start options missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to upgrade my solution to be in visual studio 2013 and my start options are now missing

[image: Missing start options]

Does anyone know how to repair them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I was running the express version of visual studio by mistake. Express version doesn't have Start actions.